# SQL Server performance

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, performance

I created a simple website (using C#) that import 70k rows data from a text file to my database but I got this problem:

It takes 3 minutes to import 70k rows data to database on my desktop (DELL optiplex 3010, 4GB ram, Windows7, no RAID) but takes more than 15 minutes to import to database on server IBM (IBM 3650 M3, Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP1, 60GB ram, RAID 10, instaled only SQL Server 2012 and its features).

Could you explain and give me some idea to solve the problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you importing this on the server locally or over the network? The server could be busy running other processes...like Exchange...

Comment: @Peter  I'm importing on server locally and only SQL Server 2012 is installed on my server.

Comment: Far too many variables at play here. You've used SQL Server 2008 and 2012. How are the databases defined? Was there log or file growth during the data loads? What's the source of your data - is it local or is the network involved. What about the destination? Is it local to the application or does it also to cross the network? What activity was occurring on the server versus your machine during the data load? etc

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information about your storage to answer this question.  I googled up [the specs of your server](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0850.html?Open#drives) and it appears you have a variety of storage options ranging from SSD to 15K RPM drives to 10K RPM drives to self-encrypting drives.  Similarly, I googled up [the specs of your desktop](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/optiplex-3010/pd) and didn't find a lot of information about the storage.

However, considering the other specs of the systems involved, I suspect that your storage isn't fast enough.  For example, if your desktop has an SSD and the server has 10K drives, that could do it.

I'm also assuming that both times you're uploading the text file from local storage.  If not, you also have to consider network latency.

Comment: Sorry, I forget about the storage: my desktop has a 7200 RPM drive and the server have five 10k RPM drives. I'm importing on server locally so we can skip the network latency.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your server has a low-end RAID card which forcedly disable **any** disk caching, without providing and adequate on-boart cache by itself.

I've seem many time similar pattern of low-end DELL PERC (read: LSI) controllers (H200, H300, etc): by disabling the disk's DRAM cache, they tremendously penalize I/O performance.

If you can, get a proper RAID card with a battery backupped write-back cache module.